# How to add a background square behind the image?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to recreate this:

[image: What I am trying to accomplish]

But I have not been able to do so. I tried with adding a :before on the img but that doesnt work. How would you go on about making this. It has to be responsive in the way that the background doesnt get bigger than the image.

SEO is not important so `background-image` or whatever is fine with me too.

WRITTEN IN SCSS - CHANGE IN HTML IS OK

UPDATED CODE TO ROB's ANSWER

This is the code I have so far

```
.imgbox {
        padding: 5%;
        position: relative;
        height: auto;

        .backdrop {
            position: relative;
            min-width: 100px;
            min-height: 100px;

            div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                background: rgb(208, 0, 0);
                background: linear-gradient(
                    90deg,
                    rgba(208, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
                    rgba(149, 0, 0, 1) 100%
                );

            }
                transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(5px);
        }

        .img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            transform: translateX(5px) translateY(-5px);
        }
    }
```

```html
        <div className="imgbox">
            <div className="backdrop">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <img
                className="img"
                src={'https://source.unsplash.com/400x250'}
                alt="test"
            >
        </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a self closing `<div />`. In addition, the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: even if i fix that, it doesnt work

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just use a shadow on <img>. Can easily be created with a [box-shadow generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) ?

Comment: The background box has a linear gradient, which cant be made with box shadow

Comment: @Rob: the OP is using JSX (React) or something similar. Pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @beerwin We don't know that. If he is, he needs to tag it as such.

Comment: Why not ask it then?

Comment: It is your responsibility to make yourself clear. It is not ours to guess at your intentions. [ask]

Comment: If you need gradients have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475188/how-to-make-this-type-of-button-in-html

Comment: @Rob: Since it's not a JSX related problem, I don't see any reason to have it tagged as such. We could always be a bit flexible, especially with newcomers. There's no reason to be rude. We can always ask politely.

Comment: @beerwin If it's not JSX, then the HTML is invalid and that's a problem with the question and might get it closed. Being a newcomer is no reason to allow invalid markup.

Comment: Being a long-time user doesn't entitle us to be rude. _That_ is my point. Regardless of the quality of the question. We also have the privilege to edit it any time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to get the gradient with a [pseudo-element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp):

```
.image-container::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:-24px;
  left:-24px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, firebrick); 
}
```

You can change the gradient and offset using `background`, `left` and `bottom` respectively. I'm not sure if there is a second gradient as well, to the top right? If so, you pair this with a `::before` to get a second background, and play around the with `z-index` to get the ordering correct.

Just remember - for an absolute positioned pseudo element to work, you'll need to set `position:relative` on the parent container, and `content:''`;

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/pojwdmQ).

Comment: Thx this works exactly how i wanted it to, responsive and easy. Great!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple with a box shadow.

The paddings in the parent are there to prevent it from cropping the shadow.

```css
.imgbox {
  padding: 0 0 30px 30px;
}

.imgbox .img {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: -30px 30px 0 rgb(208, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
      <img
          class="img"
          src='https://source.unsplash.com/400x250'
          alt="test"
      />
</div>
```

Comment: Even though the linear gradient doesn't work on this, you have been the only helpful person on this. Thank you. I will use this just in case of due to its very easy integration and responsiveness.